# Stateful and Stateless EJBs - what exactly initiates the State?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

By definition, Stateful EJBs retain state between calls, while Stateless beans don't.

My app is organized as follows:

```
app.ear
   |-EJB
      |-Local Stateful bean
      |-Local Stateless bean
   |-WAR
      |-Servlet - injects the beans via @EJB and can trigger an EJB method
```

Both beans implement a common business interface with one method. Method is implemented as a simple int count++ with output to console.

Stateless bean clearly retains conversation scope with the caller - the Servlet. It accurately increments with every method call the Servlet makes. And Servlet is called multiple times from different browsers with different *http* sessions.

Why the state is preserved?

And another inconsistency - Both Stateful/Stateless EJBs are said to have their lifecycles begin when client invokes some of their methods for the first time. While i found this to be true for Stateless beans, the Stateful one's lifecycle began (@PostConstruct method got called) as soon as it's injected via @EJB - without any invocation of any of its methods.